# How to pass and then use custom command line flags in Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Currently, I am running my angular application using the below command.

`ng serve -ssl true --host test.com` which runs the app on https://test.com:4200

Next, I am looking for how to pass a custom flag/parameter along with the command `test="ABC"` and then capture the flag in the code (mainly in environment.ts).

I followed a few blogs on medium.com nothing much helpful.

Comment: I'm afraid [it's not possible](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13937#issuecomment-473821704) Although, as a workaround you may want to introduce custom environments and use different variables stored there.

Comment: yes. Different environment files which can then be triggered using --configuration option. You can have a base config and then override using JSON spread feature.

Comment: @E.Maggini, can you guys provide any lead on that

Answer (score 1):

In your `src` directory you should have an `environments` directory.

Within, there is an `environment.ts` file which is the default.

Personally, what I would do is create an `environment.default.ts` file which holds all default configs.

Change `environment.ts` to look something like:

```
import { environment as defaults } from './environment.default`

export const environment = {
  ...defaults,
OTHER-VALUES-HERE
}
```

Note that `...` is the spread operator for json, which will take all values from the default and add it to the new JSON object.

THEN, you can replicate this pattern for other configs. For example:

`environment.test-variables.ts`

and add your custom variables. Really, this is the purpose of the environment files. [Suggest reading up on them here.](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-using-environmental-variables-organize-build-configurations)

As it says in that article, you will then need to add the new configs to your angular.json configurations section.

For example, here is a sample fragment:

```
"configurations": {
   "test" : {
     "fileReplacements" : [
       { 
         "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
         "with" : "src/environments/environment.test-variables.ts"
       }
     ]
    }
   }
```

You can then run `ng serve --configuration="test"` and access the variables.